Is there a word in English specifically for any dream during sleep?
The word dream have two main dictionary meanings:

a series of events or images that happen in your mind when you are sleeping
something that you want to happen very much but that is not very likely

It there a word in English specifically for meaning 1?
When I was asking this question (before rewrite), I thought that without context, 2 is the main meaning. For example, in a sentence without prior context "I had/have a dream climbing a mountain": had/have possibly switches 1/2 meaning.
Something that includes nightmare and the opposite of it could be a good answer, but I'm not aware of such a word. And visions are even further than nightmare from modern non-superstitious understanding of sleep.

What's wrong with dream? a series of events or images that happen in your mind when you are sleeping. For a waking dream there is 'daydream'.

On a more formal side they are “sleep brain activities.”

How would you know you have had a dream, without being conscious of it? (Another term from the edited addition is a lucid dream). I don't get what you are asking (and AI output isn't suitable material to post here).

@WeatherVane I thought that when a dream is mentioned without context, sleep is not implied - i.e. it's not "first grade" association, but something that must have at least time of day context. That's just quite unexpected for me to realise that such a common experience may not have a specific word - not good or bad, just unexpected and interesting.

Sleep is implied by 'dream' unless the context says otherwise (e.g. "Sorry, I was dreaming"), otherwise we qualify it as daydream, reverie, ambition, etc.

@WeatherVane "Sleep is implied by 'dream' unless the context says otherwise" - can you please post this as possible answer? This is not expected to me, and will be an accepted answer if no alternative.

I think the dictionary entry answers it.

"night vision" maybe?

@KarmaPeasant sure vision is closest, yet too folk and too far from modern science. Thanks, updated the question,

The term "sleeping dream" is sometimes used to contrast with waking dreams, etc.

Don't confuse dream (while sleeping) with daydreaming (while awake). Also, dream has two meanings. See Kate's answer.

If you look up dream in a dictionary, you will find that the 'images seen in the mind when asleep' definition is the primary meaning.

I had a dream last night about climbing a mountain.

The secondary meaning is 'something you would like to happen to you that isn't very likely'.

I dream of [one day] being able to climb a mountain.

The meaning is usually obvious from the context.

Some things are just this simple. :)

After also checking this word associations with weights from LLM: sleep (0.9), night (0.8), fantasy (0.7), vision (0.6), aspiration (0.6), accepting this. LLM is not yet reliable on itself (is there around a more reliable weighted associations tool actually?), but combined with clear opinions here, it's very convincing, thanks!

You might note that the secondary definition has its origins in metaphorical reference to the primary definition.

For practical purposes, Kate Bunting's accepted answer is fine, but it's more of a frame challenge ("The meaning is usually obvious from the context").  In my work, I routinely ask people if their dreams have changed, in a context which absolutely does not make the meaning clear.  I always need to disambiguate.  However, it's a pretty specialized context, and that's not why I'm proposing a different answer.  I just think the question's interesting, that's all.
As a single word for a dream specifically during sleep, I propose "REM"
I'll now address a few potential objections:
REM is an acronym comprising three words.  But it's an acronym, not an initialism, i.e. pronounced as one word, like "LASER" or "AIDS"
It doesn't stand on it's own, should really be two words "REM episode"  In speech, this might be true, but, at least in writing, the ALL CAPS spelling ensures that the meaning is clear without the second word.
REM is an electrochemical brain process, whereas a dream is subjective experience.  But the original question doesn't specify that the answer must be based on a mind-body dualist philosophy.  REM episodes are dreams because all subjective mental experiences are electrochemical brain processes:  that's my story and I'm sticking to it.
